# I want my code to run consecutively/synchronously in the background (DispatchQueue)

Tags: swift, queue, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

I want `grabAllFollowingPosts()` to run only after `loadFollowing()` has finished running. These are both network calls so I want to run them in the background. Any ideas on why my code isn’t working?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).sync {
    self.loadFollowing()
    self.grabAllFollowingPosts()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What these 3 functions do is:

1. grab every user that the current user is following
2. for each of those users, grab their posts

Hence, `loadUsers()` must run before `grabAllFollowingPosts()`

```
var followingUsers = [String]()

//Function 1: load the poeple you are following into the followingUsers array
func loadFollowing () {
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Following").document(userID).collection("UserFollowing")
    firestoreRef.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil {
            //error retrieving documents
            print (error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // document retrival successful
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            for document in snapshot.documents {

                let data = document.data()
                let userid = data["UserID"] as? String ?? "anonymous"

                self.followingUsers.append(userid)
            }
        }
    }
}


//Function 2: for all of the users in the followingUsers array - grab their documents from Firestore
func grabAllFollowingPosts () {
    for users in followingUsers {
        loadPosts(theUsers: users)
    }
}

//Function 3: loads the posts
func loadPosts (theUsers: String) {
    let firestoreRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts").whereField("UserID", isEqualTo: theUsers).whereField("Date", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Date()).limit(to: 8)
    //TODO: add infinate scroll
    firestoreRef.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //error retrieving documents
            print (error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // document retrival successful
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            for document in snapshot.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let ageRestriction = data["AgeRestriction"] as? String ?? "Age E"
                let category = data["Category"] as? String ?? "Error - No Category"
                let date = data["Date"] as? Date ?? Date()
                let documentId = data["DocumentID"] as? String ?? "Error - No Document-ID"
                let description = data["Description"] as? String ?? "Error - No Description"
                let location = data["Location"] as? String ?? "Error - No Location"
                let title = data["Title"] as? String ?? "Error - No Title"
                let userId = data["UserID"] as? String ?? "Error - No User-ID"
                let username = data["Username"] as? String ?? "Anonymous"
                let color = data["Color"] as? String ?? "Sale"

                let newPost = Post(documentIDText: documentId, usernameText: username, titleText: title, locationText: location, dateText: date, descriptionText: description, ageText: ageRestriction, category: category, uid: userId, color: color)
                self.posts.append(newPost)
            }
            if self.posts.isEmpty {self.goFollowPeopleImage.isHidden = false}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post `loadFollowing()` function and `grabAllFollowingPosts`

Comment: @Rob here are the 2 functions you asked for

Comment: By the way, that dispatch to the global queue is unnecessary because these methods run asynchronously already. And if you needed to dispatch to the global queue, you should use `async`, not `sync`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two basic patterns:

1. When dealing with RESTful network requests, we give all of our network routines a completion handler closure, which we call when the network request is done. That way, the caller can invoke each subsequent step in the completion handler of the prior step.

   There are many variations on this theme (asynchronous `Operation` subclasses, futures/promises, etc), but the idea is the same, namely chaining a series of asynchronous tasks together in such a way that the caller can know when the requests are all done and can trigger the UI update.
2. On the other hand, when dealing with Firestore, we can add observers/listeners to update our UI as updates come in. The `addSnapshotListener` closure is repeatedly called as the underlying database is updated. In this scenario there isn’t a “ok, we’re done, update the UI” point in time (so we wouldn’t generally use the completion handler approach), but rather we just continually update the UI as the documents come in.

But while your example is using `addSnapshotListener`, it also is using the `limit(to:)`, which adds a wrinkle. It’s a bit like the first scenario (e.g., if you’re limited to 8, and you retrieved 8, the listener won’t get called again). But it’s also a bit like the second scenario (e.g., if limiting to 8 and you currently have only 7 posts, it will retrieve the first seven and call that closure; but if another record comes in, it will call the closure again, this time with the 8<sup>th</sup> document as well).

Trying to handle both limited/paginated responses and listening for realtime updates can get complicated. I might suggest that if you want to make Firestore act like a RESTful service, I might suggest using `getDocuments` instead of `addSnapshotListener`, eliminating this complexity. Then you can use the completion handler approach recommended by others. It makes it behave a bit like the RESTful approach (but, then again, you lose the realtime update feature).

---

In case you’re wondering what the realtime, second scenario might look like, here is a simplified example (my post only has “text” and “date” properties, but hopefully it’s illustrative of the process):

```
func addPostsListener() {
    db.collection("posts").addSnapshotListener { [weak self] snapshot, error in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
            print(error ?? "Unknown error")
            return
        }

        for diff in snapshot.documentChanges {
            let document = diff.document

            switch diff.type {
            case .added:    self.add(document)
            case .modified: self.modify(document)
            case .removed:  self.remove(document)
            }
        }
    }
}

func add(_ document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    guard let post = post(for: document) else { return }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.posts.count, section: 0)
    posts.append(post)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}

func modify(_ document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    guard let row = row(for: document) else { return }
    guard let post = post(for: document) else { return }
    posts[row] = post
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}

func remove(_ document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    guard let row = row(for: document) else { return }
    posts.remove(at: row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}

func row(for document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Int? {
    posts.firstIndex {
        $0.id == document.documentID
    }
}

func post(for document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Post? {
    let data = document.data()

    guard
        let text = data["text"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["date"] as? Timestamp
    else {
        return nil
    }

    return Post(id: document.documentID, text: text, date: timestamp.dateValue())
}
```

But this approach works because I’m not limiting the responses. If you do use `limit(to:)` or `limit(toLast:)`, then you’ll stop getting realtime updates when you hit that limit.